# preg_split after a word and a colon

Tags: php, preg-split

I try to `preg_split` after a word and a colon.

That works for me if I split after a word:

```
$split = preg_split('/\b(\w*WORD\w*)\b/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Now I'm looking for something to split afer my word+colon.
Like `Car:`

Comment: Just add `:` like so: `/(\w*WORD\w*):/`? PS: no need to use word boundaries `\b` in this context.

Comment: Perfect :) works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?
`(\w*:)`

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fxD

Answer (score 1):

use this :

your call:

pattern : `/\\b(\\w*WORD\\w*)\\b:/` 
 subject : `a sentence before word WORD:a sentence after word`

```
$returnValue = preg_split('/\\b(\\w*WORD\\w*)\\b:/', 'a sentence before word WORD:a sentence after word', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

result:

```
array (
  0 => 'a sentence before word ',
  1 => 'WORD',
  2 => 'a sentence after word',
)
```

and i suggest to use this online tools :  https://www.functions-online.com/preg_split.html

Comment: Thx for sharing tool :)